# how to increase the default size of HeaderButton in MGWT

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I want to increase the default size of HeaderButton Widget in MGWt.I tried this:

```
headerBackButton.setHeight(String.valueOf(50)+"px");
    headerBackButton.setWidth(String.valueOf(50)+"px");
    headerBackButton.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(50, Unit.PX);
    headerBackButton.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(50, Unit.PX);
```

Comment: I tried in all above scenarios, But still I'm unable to increase its size

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried in the mgwt.showcase (class UIViewImpl) and using the `headerBackButton.setWidth("75px");` works perfect (*just after `headerBackButton = new HeaderButton();`* ).

Have you checked you do not have other elements or other css´rules that block the resize??

For example, in the mgwt showcase after `80px` the button does not get bigger because the `p` child element has the rule `max-height`

Comment: We need to see the error. I told you I have checked it before posting, and it worked...